# Can @DataSourceDefinition annotation be used in Spring Context?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee-6

Can I use the new `@DataSourceDefinition` instead of declaring the `Datasource` in a Spring Context?

```
@DataSourceDefinition(name="java:global/MyApp/MyDataSource",
      className="com.foobar.MyDataSource",
      portNumber=6689,
      serverName="myserver.com",
      user="lance",
      password="secret"
   )
```

Using a URL:

```
@DataSourceDefinition(name="java:global/MyApp/MyDataSource",
    className="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource",
    url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/myDB",
    user="lance",
    password="secret"
 )
```

An example lookup of the DataSource from an EJB:

```
@Stateless
 public class MyStatelessEJB {
   @Resource(lookup="java:global/MyApp/myDataSource")
    DataSource myDB;
      ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation,

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/

spring doesn't know about this annotation.

But, as always, you can use Spring's `@Configuration` annotation to declare your datasource within code:

Example:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        // instantiate, configure and return DataSource
    }
}
```

Other examples are here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html

If you need access to JNDI resource, you can use Spring's jee namespace (xml configuration), explained in: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee, section C.2.3 The jee schema.

Example:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/MyJdbcDataSource" />
```